# How to iterate a foreach loop starting from the last element in php?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a resultset fetched from database in laravel through this code.

```
$products = Product::whereNull('box_size')->get();
```

There are about 18000 objects in $products variable. I need to get the previous object of the last object from the list. How can I do so? Is there any way to iterate through a foreach loop from the last of a resultset?

Comment: Reverse the order in the database lookup?

Comment: Suppose you have `18000` id on the list. Now which row  you want, i mean id? 17999?

Answer (score 1):

If you only need that one record, be more precise in your query to avoid a lot of extra data loading and processing:

```
$products = Product::whereNull('box_size')
                   ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                   ->skip(1)
                   ->take(1)
                   ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not think this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from your model easily (for last 10 query) :

```
$products = Product::orderBy('id', DESC)->whereNull('box_size')->take(10)->get();
```

For just last query :

```
$products = Product::orderBy('id', DESC)->whereNull('box_size')->first();
```

Or, With foreach loop get only 10 result :

```
@php
    $i= 0;
@endphp

@foreach($all as $data) {
   $i++;
   include $data->name;
   if($i == 10) break;
 }
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

A mentioned above you can do so through your model:

`$products = Product::latest()->whereNull('box_size')->get();`

This will give you eloquent for all products sorted by DESC in column created_at.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can sort the results with descend order, and then the second item is what you want:

```
$products = Product::orderBy('id', DESC)->whereNull('box_size')->get();
$item = $products[1];
```

2. Directly access the item from the Collection object:

```
$products = Product::whereNull('box_size')->get();

$item = $products->get($products->count() - 2);

//or pop
$products->pop()
$item = $products->pop();
```